# Undefined Values inside a object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I Want to populate a page with data from the server, and be able to change the information, for This I'm using formbuilder to bring data from the server as default value using this:

```
 createForm(){
    this.getGeral()
    this.getTiposTarefas()
    this.formulario = this.fb.group({
      'tipo_tarefa':[this.tarefa.tipoTarefa.id, Validators.compose([Validators.required])], // Cant set default values cuz the array is object is undefined
      'data_tarefa': [this.tarefa.data_tarefa, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],// Cant set default values cuz the array is object is undefined
      'inicio_tarefa': [this.tarefa.inicio, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],// Cant set default values cuz the array is object is undefined
      'fim_tarefa': [this.tarefa.fim, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]// Cant set default values cuz the array is object is undefined
   });
  }
```

But I it gets undefined. I Tried console.log() inside de subscribe function and the object 'Tarefa' is populated, but out of the function scope it is not.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavParams, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { TarefadetalheService } from './tarefadetalhe.service';
    import { Tarefa } from '../../models/tarefa.model';
    import { TipoTarefa } from '../../models/tipotarefa.model';

    import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-tarefas-detalhe',
      templateUrl: './tarefas-detalhe.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./tarefas-detalhe.page.scss'],
    })
    export class TarefasDetalhePage implements OnInit {
     idTarefa = null
     tarefa: Tarefa
     tiposTarefas : TipoTarefa[]
     formulario: FormGroup
      constructor(
        private navParams: NavParams,
        private getTarefaDetalhe: TarefadetalheService,
        private modalController:ModalController,
        public fb: FormBuilder) {   }

      ngOnInit() {

        this.createForm()
      }

      getGeral(){
        this.idTarefa = this.navParams.get('id_tarefa');
        this.getTarefaDetalhe.recuperaDetalhes().subscribe((data: Tarefa)=>{ //passar o id da tarefa como parametro no recupera detalhes
        this.tarefa = data
       })
      }

  getTiposTarefas(){
    this.getTarefaDetalhe.recuperaTiposTarefas().subscribe((data: TipoTarefa[])=>{
    this.tiposTarefas = data
    console.log(this.tiposTarefas) // here it has information
    })
    console.log(this.tiposTarefas) // here it has not information
  }

  createForm(){
    this.getGeral()
    this.getTiposTarefas()
    this.formulario = this.fb.group({
      'tipo_tarefa':[this.tarefa.tipoTarefa.id, Validators.compose([Validators.required])], // Cant set default values cuz the array is object is undefined
      'data_tarefa': [this.tarefa.data_tarefa, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],// Cant set default values cuz the array is object is undefined
      'inicio_tarefa': [this.tarefa.inicio, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],// Cant set default values cuz the array is object is undefined
      'fim_tarefa': [this.tarefa.fim, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]// Cant set default values cuz the array is object is undefined
   });
  }
 closeModal()
 {
   this.modalController.dismiss();
 }
}
```

When I Run Ionic serve it throws me the error below and I can't set default values on the formcontrols:

[image]

MY HTML:

```
<ion-content padding *ngIf="tarefa != null">
  <form [formGroup]="formulario">
    <h4>
      <ion-icon name="list-box"></ion-icon> Geral
    </h4>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="8">
            <ion-label position="floating">Tipo de Tarefa</ion-label>
          <ion-select [formControlName]="tipo_tarefa" okText="Confirmar" cancelText="Cancelar">
            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let tipo of tiposTarefas" [value]="tipo.id">{{tipo.descricao}}</ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    <h4>
      <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon> Horário
    </h4>
    <ion-item-divider></ion-item-divider>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="5">
          <ion-label position="stacked">Data</ion-label>
          <ion-datetime  [formControlName]="data_tarefa" display-format="DD-MM-YYYY" max="2050-10-31" picker-format="DD-MM-YYYY"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="3">
          <ion-label position="stacked">Inicio</ion-label>
          <ion-datetime  [formControlName]="inicio_tarefa" display-format="HH:mm" picker-format="HH:mm" ></ion-datetime>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="3">
          <ion-label position="stacked">Fim</ion-label>
          <ion-datetime  [formControlName]="fim_tarefa" display-format="HH:mm" picker-format="HH:mm"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    <h4>
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon> Cliente
    </h4>
    <ion-item-divider></ion-item-divider>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Conclusion: you have to do the processing inside of the subscribe callback. Execute the line `this.formulario = this.fb.group(...)` inside of `getTiposTarefas` (in the callback).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Initiate the this.formulario = this.fb.group({ form creation only after you have received all the data from the 2 functions you are calling before it.

Comment: @Manzurul, how can I do that? Sorry but I'm new on TS.

Comment: @TiagoSilveira Posted an answer.

Comment: @ConnorsFan It's a good Idea but I think it will make the code a bit hard to understand... Well, If i'm putting the value of the 'data' inside the this.tiposTarefa. Why i can't acess this data out of the subscribe?

Comment: @TiagoSilveira - In fact, you can access the value outside of the callback. The problem is that you try to access it **before** the callback has been executed. The subscribe callback is called later (asynchronously).

Comment: And how Can I make this asynchonous, so this way  the form will be intanciated when I get the data,.

Comment: It is already asynchronous, and you cannot make it synchronous. To use the data as early as possible, initialize your form inside of the subscribe callback. If you want to make it "less confusing" (maybe), you can pass a callback to `getTiposTarefas`, so that the initization code would still appear in the `createForm` method.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the function `getTiposTarefas()` and then make the following changes.

```
createForm(){
 this.getGeral();
 this.getTarefaDetalhe.recuperaTiposTarefas().subscribe((data: TipoTarefa[])=>{
 this.tiposTarefas = data;
 this.formulario = this.fb.group({...put the fields...});
  console.log(this.tiposTarefas) // here it has information
 })
}
```

**Update:**
You need to initialize this `tarefa: Tarefa` object first. See below

```
tarefa: Tarefa =  {
  comentarios: '',
  data_tarefa: '',
  descricao: '',
  fim: '',
  id_aprovador: '',
  id_cliente: '',
  id_criador: '',
  id_sala: '',
  id_sistema: '',
  id_solicitante: '',
  inicio: '',
  nome_aprovador: '',
  nome_cliente: '',
  nome_criador: '',
  nome_sistema: '',
  nome_solicitante: '',
  numero: 0,
  participante: [],
  status_tarefa: 0,
  tarefa: '',
  tipoTarefa: {
      id:'',
      interna: null,
      descricao: ''
  }
};
```

It should work fine then.

Comment: It Works, but the code is a bit confusing haha, so... Now It is throwing other error that is : formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

Comment: Thats probably in your view file you need to put <form [formGroup]="formulario">

Comment: Edited With the HTML

Comment: If you had the same formGroup and  you get error still then problem is somewhere else and need to see plunker.

Comment: Here's my repo, I don't know if it will help, but.. https://github.com/tiagosilveiraa/PManager

Comment: @TiagoSilveira With updated the answer it should work.